# How did 'mad' come to be a determiner?

Tags: grammar, etymology, parts-of-speech

There's a group of words — I think they're called *determiners* — used to indicate number in some way... like *many*, *few*, *most*, etc. During a linguistics class my professor said this was a closed group of words, and that new ones couldn't really fit in it. Then someone shouted out "There's mad people in here!" and everyone laughed. (*Mad* meaning many, the usage I'm referring to).

How did *mad* come to fit in this supposedly closed group? Are there other words that were newly coined to fit there?

Comment: I imagine it started out as "a mad crowd of people", which evolved to "a mad number of [things]", after which it was a short step to "mad [things]". But I don't have any support for such a theory, so I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Interesting. I've never encountered this usage in England. Must be a predominantly US thing.

Comment: Another usage: this question is mad interesting. Related: crazy interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it was probably never a determiner but more likely an intensifier. As such, it is a synonym for "insane" as in "That guitar player had *insane* chops." I hear it most often in terms of having "mad skills" and so forth. In such cases it doesn't mean *many*, but something more like *great* or *prodigious*.

The earliest reference I can think of offhand is from the 2000 film *Training Day*, in which Denzel Washington tells Ethan Hawke (after Hawke has single-handledly subdued two would-be rapists), "You got mad squabbles, boy." He doesn't mean "many" squabbles, but excellent capabilities in that respect.

If it is ever used to mean a quantity, I think it probably is used as an intensifier and the determiner is left out. Compare it with the Boston area's "wicked" and California's "hella" — they're all used in somewhat the same way.

Comment: I'm from New England and it irks me when people use "wicked" as an adjective instead of an adverb. "That was wicked!" they say. I wait a moment for the other shoe to drop, then say "wicked what?!"

Comment: @Jon Purdy: I am a transplant who has lived in the Boston area for over a decade. I hear it used all kinds of ways, but I will grant you that I mostly hear it adverbially, as in "Dude, that was wicked awesome!" But you'll have to allow that it is used adjectivally as well just as much. Walk into a liquor store around here and pick up a 6-pack of Pete's Wicked Ale and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acYDNlMYAaI

Comment: @Jon Purdy: Adjective *wicked* is even in the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wicked) (entry #9).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of *numerous* examples of adjectives that can tell how many.

A singular common count noun needs a determiner if it is to serve as direct object (and most other places, actually). So if *He’s got uncle* is not grammatical to you, but *He’s got mad uncle* is, then *mad* is a determiner. But that is not the case to me; both seem ungrammatical.

Comment: hehe imagine 'uncle' to be a term indicating awesomeness. "he's got mad uncle, yo!" =P.

Comment: Heh! But in that case *He's got uncle* would be grammatical too. *Mad* still wouldn’t be a determiner. (*Uncle* would be a non-count noun.)